# Adding one minute to dataframe index column Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `dataFull` where the index column is Timestamp.
I would like to add a minute to the timestamp of each row in the same dataframe.
Something like below.
Could you please help me?

```
dataFull['Timestamp'] = dataFull.index[0] + dat.timedelta(minutes=1)
```

Dataframe is in below format

I would like to have Timestamp field increase by 1 minute for each data row

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text (or original data if it's a CSV for example), [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Timestamp` is the actual dataframe index, you cannot access it as `df['Timestamp']` anymore.

First make sure the `index` is `datetime`, then add `pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)`:

```py
dataFull.index = pd.to_datetime(dataFull.index)
dataFull.index = dataFull.index + pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```